# Combine multiple git project forks of python algorithms into one

Tags: python, git

I am currently working on a project paper, where for the practical part I have one core algorithm and multiple side algorithms that kind of supplement the working of the core algorithm. They however never have to run at the same time, as one calculated stuff with those side algorithms and the core algorithm uses this precumpted data afterwards. For each of them there is a git repo I forked from and did some modifications. Also, and that is really important, all of them use some shared python libraries I wrote. At the moment, I just copy them into each repo by hand, which means that if I find a bug or do some changes, I have to manually copy and paste them into the other projects.

So my project structure at the moment is as follows

```
Repo1/
    folder/
        shared.py
Repo2/
    folder/
        shared.py
Repo3/
    folder/
        shared.py
```

Now my questions:
1. Is there a better way to share those python libraries between the projects.
2. What would be the proper git way to merge those forks into one, new repository? I thought about submodules, but does this really make sense if I'm not interested in new commits released in those repos because I already diverged too far from them?

Comment: Remember that git isn’t a dependency manager. It keeps state of code, but it doesn’t help with what code relies on what.

Answer (score 0):

[Submodule](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules) (that you considered) remains the practical solution for your shared library: that means "folder" becomes a root folder for a nested repository with your shared library in it.

Once you fix something in that shared library on one of those projects, you can commit and push, then, on each other projects:

```
git submodule update --remote
```

They would benefit from the fix immediatly.